# Create list of lists that will join previous values in list with the next one

Tags: python, list

For example I have a list

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to get list of lists like that:

```
ls = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code. See [ask].

Comment: hint: use a  list comprehension with slicing

Comment: hint 2:there is also an easier way by using two for loop

Comment: I tried iterating through list n and concatenate each number with the next one. But I cannot get what condition I have to add to that loop in order to get a correct answer.

Comment: I'll post the answer this time, but next time when asking a question always post what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry for an incorrect question format. Will do as you said next time.

Comment: Interesting to see how to make it with list comprehension as well if it is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension approach:

```
[n[:j] for j in range(1,len(n)+1)]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using two for loops

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in n:
     temp = []
     for j in range(1,i+1):
             temp.append(j)
     b.append(temp)
print(b)
```

Comment: You forgot to add an empty b list before for loop. But the rest is working fine. Thanks

Comment: oh yeah, my bad sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
f = []
i = 0
while(i<len(l)):
    f.append(l[:i])
    i+=1
print(f[1:])
```

This is the simplest solution. I hope it is clear to you. :)

Comment: Great. But it should be equal or less than len(l). Not strictly less. Thanks for solution.